# Geometric effect of linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^2$ be the linear transformation given by $T(x,y)=(x+2y,x).$

Briefly describe the geometric effect of the linear transformation $T$.

I found out the matrix representation of this transformation with respect to the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$, which is $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
I tried plotting out some coordinates as well but I couldn't see a pattern. How can I know the geometric effect of this transformation?

Comment: That is *not* a map from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$!

Comment: It is now. Just edited.

Comment: Figure out the images of lines of constant $x$ or constant $y$.

Comment: You could try to consider how it behaves on the standard basis. Maybe see what happens to a unit cube?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't quite understand. Can you be more specific? Thank you!

Comment: What word can't you understand in my sentence ?

Comment: @zo0x Yeah I tried  that. The unit cube becomes a slanted parallelogram, but how do I describe it?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Umm what are the lines of constant x and y?

Comment: Typical geometrically transformations of features would be translation, stretching, rotation, and skew transformation. You might want to describe the behavior in terms of those?

Comment: @zo0x But if the cube is in the third quadrant, the transformation is longer a parallelogram

Comment: @CJC.10 What Yves means by lines of constant x and y would be to consider what happens to the horizontal (which have costant y-value) and vertical lines (which have constant x-value).

Comment: The line x=0 is rotated by $pi/4$ while x=1 is rotated by the same angle and displaced 3 units to the right.

Comment: Consider several lines, a grid.

Comment: Nope, I'm still very lost. Can't find a way to describe this transformation

Comment: I will try posting a hint as an answer. It will be a bit too long for a comment.

Comment: https://gfycat.com/quaintelasticisopod

Answer (score 2):

To see the geometric action of the linear transformation
$$ T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
Consider the following basic geometric transformations:

**Stretching** by $ (a,b) $
$$ S = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix} $$
**Skewing** by $ c $ (in $ x $-direction)
$$ Z = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & c \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
**Mirroring**
$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
**Rotation** by $ \theta $
$$ R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix} $$
Can you somehow determine a combination of these which will produce the same transformation?

Comment: Nope, I cannot make out any combinatons...

Comment: Try to use S*Z*M and determine a,b and c.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to see the geometric effect of a linear transformation is to get the images for every vertex in a unit square and then plot all of them.

In this case you have a transformation that maps a unit square into a parallelogram:

$$\begin{align*}T\left(\mathbf{0}\right)&=\mathbf{0}\\T\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right]&=\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right]\\T\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right]&=\left[\begin{array}{c}3\\1\end{array}\right]\\T\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right]&=\left[\begin{array}{c}2\\0\end{array}\right]\end{align*}$$

And then this figure

[Unit square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA9w8.jpg)

transforms into this

[Unit square transformed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlhxE.jpg)

This is called the shear stress effect.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_stress

In your transformation there is something like a *twist*, because $y$ axis is changed into $x$ axis and $x$ axis becomes into line $y=x$. This transformation

$$T\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}2&1\\0&1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right]$$

creates the same geometric effect without the *twist*.

I hope this information is useful. And sorry for my bad English, I'm not a native speaker.